# Mac Eclipse Java Runnable JAR file not running

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I've tried creating a jar file from a working Java program written in Eclipse using several switches:  extract required libs into generated JAR; and Package required libs into generated JAR.

Both times when I double click the jar file generated I get "the java jar file could not be launched."

The console immediately after the run looks like:

```
default 13:44:12.353371 -0700   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 501, EUID: 501, GID: 20, EGID: 20
default 13:44:12.354556 -0700   CommCenter  #I CSIAppInfo.ApplicationActivationObserver: handleLSNotitifcation_sync: Application launched: <private>
default 13:44:12.356521 -0700   mds directQueryFetchResultsReply 53249 1795162112 35
default 13:44:12.364779 -0700   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 501, EUID: 501, GID: 20, EGID: 20
default 13:44:12.370418 -0700   trustd  cert[2]: AnchorTrusted =(leaf)[force]> 0
default 13:44:12.387655 -0700   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 501, EUID: 501, GID: 20, EGID: 20
default 13:44:12.407216 -0700   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 501, EUID: 501, GID: 20, EGID: 20
default 13:44:12.407719 -0700   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 501, EUID: 501, GID: 20, EGID: 20
default 13:44:15.765872 -0700   gamed   GKClientProxy: clientForBundleID:
default 13:44:15.765930 -0700   gamed   GKClientProxy: updateIfRecentlyInstalled
default 13:44:15.766436 -0700   gamed   GKClientProxy: clientForBundleID:
default 13:44:15.766471 -0700   gamed   GKClientProxy: updateIfRecentlyInstalled
default 13:44:17.626260 -0700   CommCenter  #I CSIAppInfo.ApplicationActivationObserver: handleLSNotitifcation_sync: Application exited: <private>
default 13:44:18.115640 -0700   taskgated   MacOS error: -67062
default 13:44:22.387974 -0700   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
default 13:44:24.211416 -0700   gamed   GKClientProxy: clientForBundleID:
default 13:44:24.212577 -0700   gamed   GKClientProxy: clientForBundleID:
default 13:44:24.212661 -0700   gamed   GKClientProxy: updateIfRecentlyInstalled
default 13:44:24.384978 -0700   gamed   GKClientProxy: clientForBundleID:
default 13:44:24.385060 -0700   gamed   GKClientProxy: updateIfRecentlyInstalled
default 13:44:24.385739 -0700   gamed   GKClientProxy: clientForBundleID:
default 13:44:24.385780 -0700   gamed   GKClientProxy: updateIfRecentlyInstalled
default 13:44:24.389165 -0700   CommCenter  #I CSIAppInfo.ApplicationActivationObserver: handleLSNotitifcation_sync: Application exited: <private>
```

**NOTE:** The console adds entries very quickly -- some of these may not apply

One other thing -- I have a downloaded *.jar file which runs fine.

Any thoughts?